# App crushing while running (Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, android-virtual-device, run-app

While running my app on android studio real and virtual device , it crashing on both.
Although , it runs succesfully (i mean there is no errors).

i tried clean and rebuild project , searching errors in dependencies .
I guess abdroid studio support only one app to launch it , because i have only one app running completly on my phone . Other apps always crashing .
Do i need to delete all other app project ?

Comment: hi, your question is not that much clear, could you please add more details, project structure, what you did step by step and some codes if necessary?

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: My app is a simple log in layout and i am using android studio , there is no errors , when i run my app ir crashs , it launchs for less than one second . Even it is been installed in my phone when i try to run it in real device .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i can t test my app , everytime i run it, it crashs , i dont know why .